# Inserting missing rows with imputed values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance, imputation

## Problem

How can you insert rows for missing **YEARS**, with imputed annual **SALES**.

## Progress

The following code computes the sales differences. However, it is for one year, using the explicit [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) pointer technique.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"YEAR": [1990, 1995, 2000, 1990, 1995, 2000], 
        "COUNTRY": ["USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA"],
        "STATE": ["AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ"],
        "BRANCH":["Bed", "Bed", "Bed", "Kitchen", "Kitchen", "Kitchen"], 
        "SALES": [50, 80, 100, 10, 20, 50]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

value_first = df.iloc[0][4]
value_second = df.iloc[1][4]

delta_step = (value_second - value_first) / 5 # because 5 years between

for x in range(0, 6): 
    print((x * delta_step) + value_first)
```

## Original Data

[image: Original dataset]

## Goal

The goal is to insert the yellow highlighted rows, where sales are imputed using straight-line steps between 1990 and 2000 sales figures.
[image: Destination dataset]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First fine the missing year, of each group and make that into a `merge` df

```
idx=df.groupby(['COUNTRY','STATE','BRANCH'])['YEAR'].\
       apply(lambda x : pd.Series(range(min(x),max(x)+1))).\
         reset_index(level=[0,1,2])
```

Then do merge

```
yourdf=idx.merge(df,how='left')
```

Then using `interpolate` impute the missing value

```
yourdf['SALES']=yourdf.groupby(['COUNTRY','STATE','BRANCH'])['SALES'].apply(pd.Series.interpolate)
```